# How can you make a fields Read-Only after an InfoPath form has been submitted?

Tags: list, infopath, infopath-rules

I have an InfoPath form with four different Views. What I'm looking to do is to have fields Read-Only after submission. So the user works through the sections one at a time. Would it be better to have all the fields on one page of the form? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

on submission button, apply rule to switch to new View.  In this new view make the field or whole section, of previous view, read only and new section to be editable.

for the reference for making field read only pls see [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Disable-or-set-a-control-as-read-only-by-using-conditional-formatting-60496de3-b6e7-4317-9879-7487baad9b35)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a format rule on the field to disable it if "Created" (a date field automatically populated on first save) is not blank. [image]

Alternatively, you could use a rule on load to do something similar.

I don't think cjs' answer accomplishes the goal but perhaps I am misreading his response, or I misunderstand the question.